# My wordpress site doesnt load content

Tags: wordpress

My website doesn't load content; I have to refresh to load the content. I have deactivated all my plugins and installed them but still don't know what is the problem. Here is a [link](http://nikitekstil-ks.com).

I changed `wp_allow_repair` to `true`:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: Wich .php code i have to share with you?

Comment: Yes and the editor screenshot please

Comment: wich file i have to post code .php  ?